# having trouble with php glob() pattern

Tags: php

Hi I have this requirement where files names are named as

```
365974556_5123_200x200.jpg
365974556_5123_500x500.jpg
```

where 365974556_5123 will be same (its a variable). Now i need to match the pattern to delete these files.

I tried:

```
array_map('unlink', glob(MEDIA_FILES_PATH . "contents/" . $image->image . "*.*"));
```

what im trying to do is delete all files with name starting with `$image->image` ie 365974556_5123 in this example. But Im not getting thru... i tried

```
print_r(glob(MEDIA_FILES_PATH . "contents/" . $image->image . "*.*"))
```

give me nothing.

Could you please help me on this?

I have searched and applied the solution but didn't seem to be working with me :(

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `echo` the `MEDIA_FILES_PATH . "contents/" . $image->image` path and double check that it's correct. I suspect your path is messed up somewhere.

Comment: Yes.. its was .jpg since i had it same $image->image as 365974556_5123_500x500.jpg it became `glob(MEDIA_FILES_PATH . "contents/" . 365974556_5123_500x500.jpg . "*.*")` .. Many Many thanks for suggestion. feeling silly.. lol thanks bro..